# Using newgeometry -- how to prevent moving the top outer page numbers?

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

I used \newgeometry to enlarge the printing space to include more graphs on a couple pages of my document (article class), but it moved the page number on those pages too. If I want to keep the page numbers where they were originally (in the top outer corner), what should I do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[marginratio=1:1,height=599pt,width=372pt,tmargin=125pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{Abstact}\newpage

\tableofcontents\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Overview}
\section{Historical context}\newpage

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\section{another section}

\newgeometry{left=1in, right=1in}
\restoregeometry

\appendix
\end{document}
```

Also, I want to know how to make the page numbers a little smaller.

Comment: Please complete your document to be minimal, and at least replicate the problem. You're not even using the newly created geometry in your example code...

Answer (score 1):

For adjusting left and right margins, you may better use the `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage` package instead of using geometry. Here the margins are affected in the current page itself unlike geometry.

To reduce the size of page numbers, I advice you to use `fancyhdr` package and redefine the headers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[marginratio=1:1,height=599pt,width=372pt,tmargin=125pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{Abstact}\newpage

\tableofcontents\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Overview}
\section{Historical context}\newpage
%% adjusting the size of page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\footnotesize \thepage} %% change accordingly
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%%%%
\section{another section}
\kant[1-6]
\clearpage
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
\kant[1-4]
\end{adjustwidth}

\appendix
\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition to the above, you may also re-define the `plain` pagestyle that is used in the first page.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\footnotesize \thepage} %% change accordingly
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
}
```